How do subscribers receive message only once
I have two applications, one for publishing a message and one is for receiving the message.  My question is is there a way to make sure that every user of the subscriber application receives that message only once. When I run the app, it shows me the same message every time. Below is the code for my applications:
Publisher application:
Program.cs
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
using Publisher;

var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Some_KEY", "Some_KEY");
var snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var publisher = new SnsPublisher(snsClient);
var customerCreated = new CustomerCreated
{
    Id = 1,
    FullName = "John Doe",
    MessageTypeName = "CustomerCreated"
};

await publisher.PublishAsync("arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:first_notification_test", customerCreated);


namespace Publisher
{
    public class CustomerCreated : IMessage
    {
        public int Id {  get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string MessageTypeName { get; set; }
    }
}

Subscriber application (WPF app):
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient snsClient;
        private AmazonSQSClient sqsClient;
        private string queueUrl;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private readonly List<string> _messageAttributeNames = new() { "All" };

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("some_key", "some_key");
            sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            // Subscribe SQS queue to SNS topic
            SubscribeSqsQueueToSnsTopicAsync("arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:first_notification_test", "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/test-queue");

            // Start polling SQS queue for messages
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task.Run(() => PollSqsQueueForMessages(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
        }

        private async Task SubscribeSqsQueueToSnsTopicAsync(string topicArn, string queueUrl)
        {
            var receiveRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
            {
                MessageAttributeNames = _messageAttributeNames,
                AttributeNames = _messageAttributeNames,
                QueueUrl = queueUrl
            };

            var messageResponse = await sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveRequest);
        }


Sounds like you could also solve the problem through idempotency
You can look at the deduplication ID property to implement idempotency in your clients.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html

I might not fully understand but it seems like it's only used for single producer/consumer case. In my case, there will be many users who use the same app that consumes the same message (sorry my English might be a little weird but I hope you understand).

Sounds like you have it set up right then. Is the question how to only make the message for each client show up once? So that a client who has viewed a message already does not see it again on new startup, while a client who has not seen that same message yet will still see it for the first time on startup?

Yes, that is my question! I was thinking of using a log file to record all messages that have been read, but then the log file will soon be too long. Or using an API to keep track of it is also expensive.

The typical solution would be to create multiple SQS queues, one SQS queue for each client. The SNS topic would fanout the same message to all of the SQS queues. The client would poll the queue to show the message, and then delete the message from the queue afterwards.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html
